# Gruenberger's prime path

Tags: prime-numbers

hi
i'm looking for some historical informations about Gruenberger path.
it is a path based on conjecture that every prime could be written in the form $6k+1$ and $6k-1$ (but what is the name of this conjecture?)
i don't find a lot in the net.. the best one seems to be this [site](http://bit-player.org/2010/gruenbergers-prime-path).. 
any other infos?

Comment: Every prime.... except 2 and 3. And with this exception is not a conjecture but an essentially obvious fact, see Ross' answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a conjecture that all primes (greater than 3) are of the form 6k±1, it is a fact. 6k+0,2,4 are all divisible by 2 and 6k+3 is divisible by 3. His path just uses that fact. An interesting article.